# How to explicitly identify entities from global namespace in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

Instead of using Javascript's `prototype`, I am thinking of using inheritance feature of Typescript.

I want to add few useful methods in the `class String`, which belongs to my `namespace Util`. So this `String` `implements` the global `interface String`.
How to differentiate between these two? e.g. in C++ we do something like:

```
namespace Util
{
  class String : public ::String { ...
```

What is the Typescript equivalent for `::` to inform compiler that the interface belongs to the global space?

---

<sub>**Add-on Qn**: <strike>Is the class inheritance the right alternative for Javascript `prorotype`?</strike>

[What is the alternative equivalent of Javascript "prototype" in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50830130/514235)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the Typescript equivalent for :: to inform compiler that the interface belongs to the global space?

There is no keyword for it and the request was declined : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/983

You can create a global reference to avoid name collision

```
type GlobalString = String; 
namespace Util {
  // Use GlobalString
}
```