# What is the alternative equivalent of Javascript "prototype" in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance, equivalent

Typescript provides Object Oriented & Generic programming paradigms apart from Functional programming offered by Javascript.

The keyword `prototype` is a very powerful and sometimes a dangerous tool. In general, I read that it simulates the inheritance aspect in Javascript.

So preferably, what is the [closest] alternative of `prototype` in .ts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Typescript provides Object Oriented & Generic programming paradigms apart from Functional programming offered by Javascript.

No, JavaScript itself offers an object-oriented and generic programming model and can be used in the functional programming style as well (but isn't specifically designed to support it, like Haskell).

All TypeScript does is:

- Add static type checking (this is its main purpose).
- Support early adoption of certain proposed upcoming JavaScript features via the TypeScript compiler (for instance: TypeScript's compiler supported `class` syntax very early on).
- Add some extra syntax on constructors which is unlikely ever to become a JavaScript feature: automatically copying parameters to properties.
- Add "private" properties via a `private` keyword; JavaScript will have private properties soon, but not using the syntax TypeScript uses.

Everything else is JavaScript.

When I say "all" it does, that's not to diminish those things. Static type checking, in particular, can be extremely useful, particularly in large projects.

> The keyword `prototype` is a very powerful and sometimes a dangerous tool. In general, I read that it simulates the inheritance aspect in Javascript.

`prototype` isn't a keyword, it's just the name of a property on constructor functions that refers to the object that will be assigned as the prototype of object created with the `new` keyword used with those constructors.

Inheritance isn't *simulated* in JavaScript. It's *implemented* with prototypes, see [prototypical inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

> So preferably, what is the [closest] alternative of `prototype` in .ts?

That would be: `prototype`, either explicitly or indirectly via `class`. Again, TypeScript just adds a layer of static type checking and a couple of minor syntax additions. Everything else is just JavaScript.

> Suppose if the answer is inheritance, then how to `extend` of `implement` the String kind of interfaces of JS into TS [as there can be lots of abstract methods]?

It's not very clear what you're asking here. You can either extend string:

```
class MyString extends String {
    // ...
}
```

...or add to `String.prototype`, ideally adding non-enumerable properties with functions assigned to them via [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty):

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "myAddition", {/*...*/});
```

Comment: Actually `interface String` has lots of methods and it's impractical to implement all of them. Anyhow, I have removed add-on query, as it should be better as a separate Qn. Regarding the main question, it will be helpful, if you put an example to explain how a `prototype` can be replaced with the `class` syntax.

Comment: @iammilind - `String` is a **class**, provided by JavaScript (which promotes primitive strings to instances of that class when necessary), not an interface. Re `class` syntax: [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30783217/why-should-i-use-es6-classes/30783368#30783368) compares `class` and `prototype` syntax. It's JavaScript's `class` syntax rather than TypeScripts, but again, other than the bullet points above, they're the same.